# User Name not available in stepContext.Context.Activity.From.Name when using MS Botframework V4 (c#) over WebChat using Directline channel

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

## Problem Statement

Am using MS Botframework V4 (c#) using Directline channel over MS Web Chat. Have successfully integrated with Azure Active directory and am successfully able to authenticate/ login using an Azure AD account from the MS Web Chat widget.

> **Unfortunately**  the Logged in User Name is not available in stepContext.Context.Activity.From.Name property.

## Other Details

> ***following are the values of other properties when debugged using MS Bot framework Emulator:***
> stepContext.Context.Activity.ChannelId     :   "emulator"
> stepContext.Context.Activity.CallerId       :   "urn:botframework:azure"
> stepContext.Context.Activity.From.Name      :   "User"
> stepContext.Context.Activity.From.Role      :   "User"
> stepContext.Context.Activity.TextFormat     :   "plain"
> stepContext.Context.Activity.Recipient.Name :   "Bot"

## Visual Walk Through

### Sign-In Button from ***OAuthPrompt*** dialog

[image: Sign-In Button from OAuthPrompt dialog]

### Shows Active Directory Sign-In Dialog

[image: Shows Active Directory Sign-In Dialog]

### Six Digit OTP/Token to copy and Paste as ChatBot input

[image: 6 Digit OTP/Token to copy and Paste as ChatBot input]

### Incorrect User Name after Successful Sign-in

[image: Incorrect User Name after Successful Sign-in]

### Client Side Web Chat / Direct Line code

[image: Client Side Web Chat / Direct Line code]

### MS Bot Framework Code printing the Logged-in User Name

[image: MS Bot Framework Code printing the Logged-in User Name]

## Query

Would appreciate if someone could help with getting the Logged-In user name after successfully logging-in using the Azure Active Directory credentials over MS Web chat using Direct Line channel.

Answer (score 1):

## Found the solution after some Research and Patience

Used the following code which worked after providing it mentioned Graph API permission on Active Directory [OAuth Helper Class used Graph API to Get Logged-in User Name and Password](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph).

> ***It worked seamlessly. Be a little patient after granting mentioned Graph API permissions as, it takes a little while for it to get propagated / Applied***